# Integration of HWIOAuthBundle with FosUserbundle configuration issue

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, hwioauthbundle, symfony-2.5

I have followed this article and implemented OAuth2 with Github, After successful authentication, I am getting below error.

**Unable to find the controller for path "/secure_area/login/check-github". Maybe you forgot to add the matching route in your routing configuration?**

**config.yml**

```
hwi_oauth:
    # name of the firewall in which this bundle is active, this setting MUST be set
    firewall_name: secure_area
    connect:
        confirmation: true
        #account_connector: hwi_oauth.user.provider.fosub_bridge
        #registration_form_handler: hwi_oauth.registration.form.handler.fosub_bridge
        #registration_form: fos_user.registration.form

    resource_owners:
        github:
            type:                github
            client_id:           a8b7e3e35e46271d10a5
            client_secret:       6abca3ded9a19d9e2bf52b42f017d23a745bd540
            scope:               "user:email"

    fosub:
        # try 30 times to check if a username is available (foo, foo1, foo2 etc)
        username_iterations: 30

        # mapping between resource owners (see below) and properties
        properties:
            github: githubID
```

**security.yml**

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
        secure_area:
            pattern: ^/secure_area

            oauth:
                failure_path: /secure_area/connect
                login_path: /secure_area/connect
                check_path: /secure_area/connect
                provider: fos_userbundle
                resource_owners:
                    github:           "/secure_area/login/check-github"
                oauth_user_provider:
                    service: hwi_oauth.user.provider.fosub_bridge

            anonymous:    true
            logout:
                path:           /secure_area/logout
                target:         /secure_area/connect #where to go after logout


    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/secure_area/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/secure_area/connect, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/secure_area, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing the indentation Adam.

Comment: You might want to mask out your Github security tokens next time. I would reset them on Github if you have not done so already :)

Answer (score 0):

What do you have in your routing configuration. Do you have a route setup for hwi_github_login?

> Another route named hwi_github_login was also added which is same as the callback url given during creation of Github application. This is the url which will be intercepted by the firewall to check authentication.

Your routing.yml should have:

```
hwi_oauth_redirect:
resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml"
prefix:   /secure_area/connect

hwi_oauth_login:
resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/login.xml"
prefix:   /secure_area/connect

hwi_oauth_connect:
resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/connect.xml"
prefix:   /secure_area/connect

hwi_github_login:
pattern: /secure_area/login/check-github
```